# Need to get summation formula?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I have:

$$ Y[k]= \frac 1N \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} exp^{j2\pi\epsilon n/N} $$

After simplification, I have to get:

$$ Y[k]= \frac {\sin \pi\epsilon} {N\sin(\pi\epsilon/N)} \cdot exp^{j\pi\epsilon(N-1)/N} $$
Please, help me prove this.

If I get a formula to manipulate $ \sum_{m=0}^{N-1} exp^{j\alpha n} $ , the rest will be easy.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Thanks. I have already got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$S\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} exp^{j2\pi\epsilon n/N}=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (e^{j2\pi \epsilon/N})^n$$ which is a Finite Geometric Series with common ratio $=e^{j2\pi \epsilon/N}$

$$S=\frac{(e^{j2\pi \epsilon/N})^N-1}{e^{j2\pi \epsilon/N}-1} $$

$$=\frac{e^{j2\pi \epsilon}-1}{e^{j2\pi \epsilon/N}-1}$$

Now, $\displaystyle e^{2jy}-1=e^{jy}(e^{jy}-e^{-jy})=e^{jy}(2j\sin y)$

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your quick response.